# Common refinement for simple predictable processes

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I'm trying to show that for a semimartingale $X$, the stochastic integral $\mathcal{I}_X : \mathcal{S}_{\text{ucp}} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}_{\text{ucp}}$ is cauchy continuous, since the idea is to extend its domain to $\mathbb{L}$.  I know that it is already continuous, but Protter's book says that we can extend continuous linear functions defined on dense sets. However, I think that the function must preserve cauchy sequences in order to do so. So I am trying to use the definition of the integral on simple predictable processes and the ucp topology directly to show that the integral does conserve cauchy sequences. I think this comes down to comparing simple processes. Is there a way to get a common refinement like in Riemann integration, except now with stopping times so we can write the difference in a canonical representation? For example if $H_1 = Z_0\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} Z_k\mathbf{1}_{(T_k, T_{k+1}]}$ and $H_2 = Y_0\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-1} Y_k\mathbf{1}_{(S_k, S_{k+1}]}$, is there some notion of a common refinement of the stopping times $S_k, T_k$ ... maybe $L_k$ such that $H_1-H_2 = A_0\mathbf{1}_{\{0\}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{q-1} A_kL_{(L_k, L_{k+1}]}$

Comment: I think that the best thing which we can expect is to have a representation of the form $$H_1-H_2 = A_0 1_{\{0\}} + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m A_{k,j} 1_{(L_{k,j},M_{k,j}]}$$ for stopping times $L_{k,j} \leq M_{k,j}$.

Comment: So I just read some of Protters book and he has this definition of simple predictable being that there is a canonical representation with the increasing stopping times. I think that my question as it stands boils down to showing that $\mathcal{S}$ is a vector space. Do you know how to show that? Protter never seems to mention that, so maybe it's not?  That's kind of scary since I was going to try to show that the integral was cauchy continuous using linearity, now I might not have any idea how to show that we can extend the integral from $\mathcal{S}$ to $\mathbb{L}$.

Comment: Thanks saz, I will just drop that specific canonical representation condition and define simple more loosely. That allows me to get linearity easily, and I will try to show cauchy continuity.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.